# What would be image dimensions to show every device?

Tags: android

my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <ScrollView android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/three_content_map"
            />
    </ScrollView>

    <ScrollView android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/three_content_com"/>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

second imageView doesn't shows image,"three_content_com" dimensions are 401 X 6114 and perhaps it is very big?! what size would be image dimensions to show every device perfectly.please someone give me advice.thank you

Comment: do u want to use two scroll view?

Comment: yes,I wont to make two scrollable images

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then come back and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scaleType property like this..

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

For more information refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Comment: I used it but image still vanished :/

Comment: @vano..I gave my answer according to your question's subject...and for your current problem...you have to manage the height and width os your both scrollview as well as imageviews